# Creating My own logger implementation for camel route

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-camel, slf4j, logback

Is there a way in camel to create my own logger implementation where in ill define my own logic of logging message to a log file or database deciding its INFO or WARNING or ERROR or EXCEPTION. Simple camel route.

```
from("file://E://Target//Customers")
.log("MyLogger",param1,param2..)
.to("file://E://Target//Customers//Done");
```

MyLogger should be invoked automatically on usage of it in route....
Please help me out How to Define MyLogger based on existing frameworks like slf4j, log4j, logback etc??

Comment: I understand that having log files in SQL makes it easier to analyse the logs but it makes your solution fragile.. Keep in mind log4j is not a reliable logging mechanism. When logging things to file you only have to worry about the drive being available and space being available on the drive.Logging errors to a database requires a database server being available etc. A LOT more to worry about than just a file. This makes your solution more fragile. If I can make a suggestion. Create a camel route that reads the log files and inserts errors into the database.

Comment: Just use the official (and deprecated) `org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender` or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but I will suggest that you to use the log4j that camel supports and use the support provided by the container that you use.

You can use the wire tap pattern and then within which you can use the db component for database. For file use the same wire tap and within you can create your own payload and then use the file endpoint as a producer.

Comment: Thanks for the information. sorry for being newbie, can u give a sample example of it? or any tutorial to refer??

Comment: Let me add you a code. But can you post some code where you need i so that i can fit in the logging piece there ?

Comment: from("file://E://Target//Customers")
.log("MyLogger",param1,param2..)
.to("file://E://Target//Customers//Done");                                                                        The above camel route contains .log component usage of slf4j framework. Now i wanna know how to create a my own LoggerAppender and use it in log4j properties.